# Trying to read off the process input stream

Tags: java

In the following scenario we're dealing with a console application where there is a PHP script running as a process from within a java application.  Each time the script is fed with two values and returns either "OK" or "ERR".  I'm trying to capture the time it takes from when the inputs are fed into the script and the time it return with either an "OK" or "ERR" value.

I have implemented the following fix, but it still doesn't seem to work.  If anyone could shed some light.

```
try {
        proc = runtime.exec("php " + "script.php");            


        inp = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()) );
        out = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream()) );

        while (true) {
            temp = getRandomUser() + " " + getRandomHost();
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            //System.out.println(temp);

            print(pipe(temp));

            while (!inp.readLine().equals("ERR") || !inp.readLine().equals("OK")) {
            }

            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            procTime = (long) endTime - startTime;

            fout.write(Double.toString(procTime));
            fout.newLine();
            //System.out.println("! " + procTime);
        }


} catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Thread prematurely Terminated...");
}
```

Comment: What does it do when you run the code?

Comment: It just doesn't do anything.  Seemingly goes through the loop once and that's it.  Please note that a few of these processes happen in parallel threads.

Comment: What do you mean by *"and that's it"*?  Does the code fragment end?  Does it block?  If so where?

Comment: No, it doesn't stop. The PHP script would run in the background waiting for inputs.  It just continues without doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your description of the symptoms is unclear.  However, this like is almost certainly wrong:

```
while (!inp.readLine().equals("ERR") || !inp.readLine().equals("OK")) {
}
```

Firstly, if you reach the end of stream, readLine will return `null`, and you will get an NPE when you try to invoke `equals` on it.

Second, the condition is actually calling `readLine()` twice.  It looks like you intent is to read and throw away lines until you get one that matches "ERR" or "OK".  But the code doesn't do that.  Indeed, if the first significant line it reads is "OK", the condition won't fire ... and you will keep on trying to read.  The code should be like this:

```
String line = inp.readLine();
while (line != null && !line.equals("ERR") && !line.equals("OK")) {
    line = inp.readLine();
}
```

This bug is certainly sufficient to explain why the code would block ...

Comment: Many thanks for this.  I implemented your changes and the code still stops after going through a couple of records.

Comment: You need to use a debugger ... or add traceprints ... to figure out what is actually being sent to the external process and received from it.